# How to find $\lim_{ t → ∞} \frac{\sqrt t + t^2} {4t − t^2} $

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I find
$$\lim_{ t → ∞}  \frac{\sqrt t + t^2} {4t − t^2} $$

Please show steps and explanations. I am a calculus student, thus, please do not use math jargon beyond my knowledge. I want to know enough to past my test.

Comment: Unfortunately, the formula is not understandable. Please, describe it in words, if you don't know how to use LaTeX commands. Or add an image.

Comment: @egreg That is fixed now

Comment: If the formula is the one divined by Alizter, just divide numerator and denominator by $t^2$.

Comment: Our teacher wants us to utilize the limit laws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide numerator and denominator by $t^2$ to get $$\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{\dfrac{1}{t^{3/2}} + 1}{\dfrac 4t - 1}= \frac{0+1}{0-1} = -1$$

Comment: In problems such as this I need to convert the root to a fraction?

Comment: When $t\to \infty$, divide numerator and denominator by $t$ raised to the highest degree appearing in the numerator and denominator. In this case, that is $t^2$.

Comment: I have question regarding the fractions. Why are they 0. I have been just making them 0 since that is what the instructions state, however, when it come to an infinity limit, why is it just considered 0, and as I can see by your example it applies for all fractions.

Comment: Any constant, when "divided by infinity" approaches zero because the denominator approaches infinity (making the denominator "blow up", which makes the fraction shrink to zero.

Answer (score 0):

- Hint. Take $t^{2}$ common from both numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Write
$$\frac{\sqrt t+t^2}{4t-t^2}=\frac{t^2(t^{-\frac32}+1)}{t^2(4/t-1)}=\frac{t^{-\frac32}+1}{4/t-1}$$
and see what happens to numerator and denominator as $t\to+\infty$.

Comment: Can you use the limit laws in your example?

Comment: What I wrote was mere algebra (using $t>0$). Now yo can use limit laws (i.e. as soon as you write $\lim_{t\to+\infty}$ before the expression again)

Comment: Why are fractions evaluate to be 0

Comment: That should already have been covered in your course. Evaluate them with $t=1000000$ to get a feeling.

Comment: Quite frankly the explanations in the book makes no sense to me, that is why I am asking. "If you can't explain it simply, you don't understand it well enough."

Answer (score 0):

Remove the square root by the substitution $\sqrt{t}=u$; then your limit becomes
$$
\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{u+u^4}{4u^2-u^4}
$$
Now it's a rational function and the pattern is well known: set $v=1/u$ and compute
$$
\lim_{v\to0^+}\frac{\dfrac{1}{v}+\dfrac{1}{v^4}}{\dfrac{1}{v^2}-\dfrac{1}{v^4}}=
\lim_{v\to0^+}\frac{v^3+1}{v^2-1}=-1
$$